# VueJS API result order by rank asc

Tags: json, api, sorting, vue.js, filter

I am new to VueJS and I've made a searchbar where I can search for top 100 cryptocurrency coins from CoinMarketCap. Once you enter the page you will see an overview of all top 100 coins. Everything works perfectly fine, but I want to sort the coins by rank in an ascending order.

I've started doing research on the internet and as a result I've found this

> return _.orderBy(this.users, 'name');

How do I add this code to my own code, because if I put the code above in my function it will say that you cannot return 2 things. And I if I put the code in the return the program stops working.

My ***main.js***:

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
       data: [],
       search: ''
   },
   computed: {
       filteredCoins: function() {
   if (!this.search) return this.data
           return this.data.filter((coin) => {
               return coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
           });
       }
   },
   created () {
       fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/')
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(json => {
               this.data = Object.values(json.data)
           })
   }
})
```

[FSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/134573/)

Answer (score 0):

`_.orderBy` is probably referring to the [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) function of the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) JavaScript library. You could do it that way, but JavaScript also has a built-in sort function for Arrays.

for your "filteredCoins" function try adding a `.sort` after your `.filter`. So it would look something like

```
return this.data
  .filter(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
  .sort((c1, c2) => c1.rank < c2.rank ? c1.rank === c2.rank ? 0 : -1 : 1);
```

You can find more details about how `.sort` works on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: It didn't worked for me, have you tried the code in JSFiddle? Link is under the example code

Comment: That was more of a sketch, not something I troubleshot. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/krxfoysd/) a link to a working example: